# Combinatorics problem with trees

Tags: combinatorics

*7 trees of two types are planted in a row. How many possibilities are there, such that no trees of type 1 are planted next to each other?*

I know that you can split it into 8 cases (number of type 1 trees) and count them individually, but that answer doesn't seem really nice. Is there another way of approaching this problem?

Comment: Hint;  any such arrangement must end in either $2$ or $21$.

Comment: if we denote $f(n)$ the number of ways $n$ trees are planted such way that to trees of type $1$ are planted next to each other, then: a) if the way starts with $1$, then it'can't be followed by $1$, so in this case we have $f(n-2)$ possibilities, b) the way starts with $2$ and in this case we have $f(n-1)$ possibilities. So $f(n)=f(n-2)+f(n-1)$ and we have simple recursion. Considering $f(1)$ and $f(2)$ we can compute $f(3)$, then $f(4)$ and eventually to $f(7)=34$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t_1, \; t_2$ denote a tree of type $1$ and type $2$ respectively.

Let $f(n)$ be the number of ways $n$ trees can be planted in a row such that no trees of type $1$ are planted next to each other.

We can calculate $f(n)$ using this reasoning:

- If we decide to place a $t_1$ in the first position in the row, then the number of ways to plant the rest of the trees is $f(n - 2)$ because we are obliged to place a $t_2$ right after our $t_1$.
- If we decide to place a $t_2$ in the first position in the row, then the number of ways to plant the rest of the trees is $f(n - 1)$ since there are no restrictions on the second plant (could be either $t_1$ or $t_2$).

Conclusively, $f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)$.

Obviously, $f(1) = 2$ since the ways we can place $1$ tree in a row according to the above restrictions are either $t_1$ or $t_2$. Similarly, $f(2) = 3$ since the possible ways are $t_1 t_2$, $t_2 t_1$, and $t_2 t_2$.

Finally, all you have to do is compute $f(7)$. Since $7$ is a small number, you can just list all the results of $f(n)$ from $1$ to $7$: $2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34$, from which $f(7) = 34$.